# React native keycloak unable to navigate to app screen after keycloak authenication

Tags: react-native, keycloak

I am using "@react-keycloak/native": "^0.6.4", in my app. I have succeeded log in . But I am unable to navigate to my native application screen after successful log in even after using redirectUri. Here is the App.js code.

App.js

```
export default () => {
const onKeycloakTokens = useCallback((tokens) => {
if(!tokens.token) {
  // remove from storage
} else {
  console.log("ReactNativeKeycloakProvider onKeycloakTokens:",tokens.token);
  //save to storage tokens.token
}
});
return (
<MenuProvider>
  <Provider store={store}>
  <ReactNativeKeycloakProvider 
    authClient={keycloak}
    initOptions={{redirectUri:"com.example.name://SampleBlank",
      
    // ---------- OTHER METHODS TRIED ----------
    // redirectUri:"name://SampleBlank",
    // redirectUri:"./src/screens/SampleBlank",
    // redirectUri:"example.name://SampleBlank",
    }}
    // LoadingComponent = {LoginScreen}
    //events : onReady, onInitError, onAuthSuccess, onAuthError, onAuthRefreshSuccess,onAuthRefreshError,onTokenExpired,onAuthLogout
    onEvent= {(event,error) => {
      console.log("Keycloak event :",event,error);
    }}
    isLoadingCheck={(keycloak) => {
      console.log("Authenticated",keycloak.authenticated)
      return !keycloak.authenticated
    }}
    onTokens={onKeycloakTokens}

  >  
    <App/>
    </ReactNativeKeycloakProvider>
    <CustomAlert />
    <ModalPortal />
   
  </Provider>
  </MenuProvider>
);
};

 const App =  (props) => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen"
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SplashScreen"
          component={SplashScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen 
         name = "SampleBlank"
         component= {SampleBlank}
         options = {{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={(props) => ({
            headerStyle: {
              elevation: 0,
              shadowOpacity: 0,
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
              backgroundColor: '#F3F6FF', //Set Header color
            },
            headerLeft: null,
            // opacity: 0,
            //Set Header text color
            headerTitle: '',
          })}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   );};

const Dashboard =  props => {
 var  initRoute = JSON.stringify(props.route.params.screen);
 return (
<Bottom.Navigator
  initialRouteName={initRoute}
  >
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="DashboardScreenStack"
    component={DashboardScreenStack}
  />
 
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="Others"
    component={Others}
  />
 
</Bottom.Navigator>
);};

const DashboardScreenStack = props => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={DashboardScreen}>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="DashboardScreen"
    component={DashboardScreen}
    options={{headerShown: false}}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
);};

 const Others = props => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Test}>
   <Stack.Screen
    name="Test"
    component={Test}
    options={{headerShown: false}}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
);};
```

I have tried different ways to add ReactNativeKeycloakProvider "redirectUri" . But none of it worked.
I tried those with reference to redirectUri given in react-native-keycloak example as redirectUri:"myapp://HomeScreen".
I want to load SampleBlank or Dashboard on successful login.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

my App.ts configuration:

```
  <ReactNativeKeycloakProvider
    authClient={keycloak}
    initOptions={{'myappname://Home'}}
  >
    <Navigation />
  </ReactNativeKeycloakProvider>
```

And Login.ts:

```
  if (keycloak?.token) {
    navigation.navigate('Home')
  }
  if (keycloak?.authenticated) {
    navigation.navigate('Home')
  }
```

and have a buttom: onPress={() => keycloak?.login()}
But i dont get token after keycloak login, it redirect a blank page browserpage, i want to navigate home with keycloak token